# How can I create a method without parameters in java?

Tags: java

I've been trying to write some code in java and I have some lines that I write in a lot of places(exactly the same). I want to replace those lines everywhere with a method. Is that possible ?

For example

```
public fill()
{       x=x+1;
        if( x == sizeX){
            y=y-1;
            x=0;
        }
}
```

Those variables x,y,size are defined outside the method. I also tried with public void , void and a lot of other combinations that I could find. Is it possible what I am trying to do in java ?

Comment: `public void fill()` should work.

Comment: Yes, what you want to do is possible.  Your method will need to specify its return type (`void`), but otherwise, what you have included above is the right idea.

Comment: also `sizeX` is a field? (`public void fill()`)

Comment: This will only work if your variables (x and y) are declared at the class level.

Comment: I know that it will work by declaring them in the method . I was wondering if I could use them from outside that

Comment: @Bogdan yes you can declare them outside the method, as long as they are in the same class as mentioned by Justine and not inside another method.

Comment: "*I also tried with public void , void and a lot of other combinations that I could find.*" adding `void` after `public` is necessary (if you don't want your method to return anything) but if this doesn't solve your problem it means that there is another problem in your code. So try to [edit] your question and post exact compiler error with [code which will let us reproduce it](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Test{
    private int x, y, sizeX;    

    public void fill(){
         x=x+1;
         if( x == sizeX){
            y=y-1;
            x=0;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to make a new class. I was asking if it is possible to make a method in the main class that will use outside parameters and modify them, without declaring them in the method.

Comment: In my example the variables are not declared inside the method. It is declared in the class and fill() method uses them directly.

Comment: I have only this class "public static void main(String[] arg) { " And the method is in that class . Should I declare every variable with the word private ?

Comment: It is not a class. It is a method of a class. It is the main() method.

Comment: I use the variables x,y in other places too . If I declare them as private in that class, I think that the main method won't be able to use them anymore.. or ?

Comment: the main method can use them because they are in the same class. If you will use them inside main, you should make the variables and methods static.

Comment: I tried everything, but it just won't work. I will just keep using those lines everywhere. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From JLS §8.4.5:

> The result of a method declaration either declares the type of value
>   that the method returns (the return type), or uses the keyword void to
>   indicate that the method does not return a value.

You forgot the return type of your method. Since your method does not return a value, the return type should be `void`.

Also, this method should be in a class with fields.

```
public class Foo{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int sizeX;    

    public void fill(){
         x=x+1;
         if( x == sizeX){
            y=y-1;
            x=0;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried with that, but when I run it I get 'illegal start of expression'

Comment: just add "void" before fill, it should work..

Answer (score 0):

HTH

```
public class TestMethod {

    static int x, y , sizeX;

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        x = 9;
        y = 200;
        sizeX = 10;

        System.out.println("x/y/sizex :" + x + "/" + y + "/" + sizeX);
        fill();     
        System.out.println("x/y/sizex :" + x + "/" + y + "/" + sizeX);              
    }

    static void fill(){
        x=x+1;
        if( x == sizeX){
            y=y-1;
            x=0;
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't want to declare any variables, I want to use the outside of the method ones. I just want to call that method, and when I do it will just start modifying x and y.

Comment: In somewhere you must declare your variables

Comment: the variables are declared in the main class. I was asking if I can write a method that uses those variable and modifies them

Comment: Here is a simple description about variable scope in java. [Java Scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)

Comment: Check edits, you declare variables outside method into main class - TestMethod, and change values after call it.